Char pointer versus array between multiple compilation units
If you need ROM maps in memory that you will access in different compilation units you can allocate the memory in the first unit:
extern const unsigned char BPG_Arial29x32[] = {
    // Font Info
    0x00,                   // Unknown #1
    0x00,                   // Unknown #2
...
}

In the other unit there are two options to declare in the headers:
extern const unsigned char* BPG_Arial29x32;

OR
extern const unsigned char BPG_Arial29x32[];

The second is always working, and the first let the software 'hang' if you use it in that way:
inline static map<const unsigned char*, const char*> fontSoftToString = {
    {BPG_Arial29x32, "BPG_Arial29x32"}
};

inline static map<string, const unsigned char*> stringToSoftFont = {
    {"BPG_Arial29x32", BPG_Arial29x32}
};

But it works if you use it as a function parameter:
declare: SetTextFontRom(const unsigned char* font)
use: SetTextFontRom(BPG_Arial29x32);

Why is this and why this is not 'compatible'?

it is worth mentioning what compiler you are using and when does the hanging occur, at program start up ? or when used somewhere ? it could be some compiler bug.

Declaration extern .... (no initialization) should be in header file and definition without extern in single cpp file.

When you pass an array as a function argument, you're not actually passing the array but a pointer to its first element (that is, an entirely different object). This is different from claimig that the same object has two entirely different types.

C++ inherits a lot of behavior from C.  A C++ array and a C array have very different behavior.  If you use a C++ array instead of a C array, does the problem go away?

this is an ODR violation.

One and only one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used (see below) is required to appear in the entire program (including any standard and user-defined libraries). The compiler is not required to diagnose this violation, but the behavior of the program that violates it is undefined.

each definition consists of the same sequence of tokens (typically, appears in the same header file)
further down


then if we head over to compatible types

Note: C++ has no concept of compatible types. A C program that declares two types that are compatible but not identical in different translation units is not a valid C++ program.

note that even in the C standard, arrays and pointer types are not compatible types, so this is invalid C code.
MSVC bugs out with a good descriptive message:

redefinition; different types of indirection

Arrays and pointers are not the same type (sizeof one is  N bytes and the other is 8 bytes), array names implicitly decay to pointers whenever needed (see Array-to-pointer decay), but what you are looking at is some linker "bug" where it likely used the content of the array itself to fill the pointer instead of its address, due to the ODR violation, which it is allowed to do according to the standard.

IIRC when I once tried a similar thing to this option 1, I got undefined symbol error at linking (and thanks to it was able to figure out that I shouldn't do this), so I agree OP only got this far because linker isn't strict enough in his case.
